# One Main Page and Navigation using CSS

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

I'm trying to create my first website using HTML/CSS.  My goal here is to have one single main page, and when a person clicks the navigation links, it updates the main-content portion of the index.html file (but doesnt update the rest of the content like header and footer).  I would also like it to keep the background color a different color than the rest.  I'm hoping to reduce the duplicate html code while using as little js as possible (preferably all CSS, but I'm not sure thats possible).  For example, if you where to click on the Contact link, you would end up with the following:

[image: Header and Link Selection]

When clicking on the link, it updates the "main-section" below using js.

```
 <body>
  <div id="main-container">
   <div id="header-section">
    <div class="header-content">Header Text</div>
    <div id="header-navigation">
     <ul>
      <li><a class="NavClick" href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="NavClick" href="Photos.html">Photos</a></li>
      <li><a class="NavClick" href="Programming.html">Programming</a></li>
      <li><a class="NavClick" href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a class="NavClick" href="About.html">About</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div id="main-section"></div>
   <div id="footer-section">
    <div class="footer-content">
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

Here is the js:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#main-section').load('Home.html'); // Default
   $('.NavClick').click(function(e)
   {
      var url = $(this).attr('href');
      if(!url.match('^http'))
      {
         e.preventDefault();
         $('#main-section').load(url);
      }
   });
});
```

Most of the [examples](http://www.apaddedcell.com/highlight-links-current-page-css) I have scene about updating the background color of the navigation links use tricks based on loading complete new pages that have `body` id's.  I only have one page (so only one body tag ever) and I use js to update the main-content.  I'm curious if there is a way to have one main page with navigation and allow navigation highlighting.  The only thing I've really come up with, but I dont really like, is using the js like this:

`$('.NavClick').css('background','transparent');`
`$('.NavClick').css('color','white');`

I would like an HTML/CSS solution if possible (ie, no SSI, php, etc).

Comment: Won't this break the browser's back-button functionality?

Comment: @Bazzz - Yup, looks like it does.  Just goes back to the last page before entering my site no matter which links on the navigation are clicked (or how often).  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yeah, the better way would be, to do regular postbacks and not to load the content dynamically using AJAX :-) For preserving back button functionality with AJAX have a look at [jQuery BBQ: Back Button & Query Library](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/)

Comment: @Dave - Thanks for the link. Yeah this is my first time trying this, and I just couldnt see why people would want to duplicate all the navigation and footer content in each page. Seems like there should be a better way to handle this, but maybe thats why there is SSI/php/etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it right, you are just looking for a solution to change the menu links backgrounds depending on which one was clicked. Since you're using jQuery already, I'd recommend the following solution:

jQuery:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

CSS:

```
a.selected {
    background-color: #ddf;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/TqxHq/

Comment: This is definitely a better way to do it than I was thinking, thanks!

Comment: There are some CSS only solutions for Tabs (e.g. http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/target.html) but I'm not sure if they can be used/adjusted for this case...

Comment: Interesting solution. Looks like it uses iframes, which I've heard is slower, but maybe this would work.  Seems to support the browser back button too.

Answer (score 1):

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/

Very nice solution for what you want!

Comment: Yeah, that looks pretty close.  It doesnt appear to keep the current page navigation link a different color.  Do you know how to change it to get a different look to the navigation links when clicked?  Plus Im still hoping for a non js way to do this.  Thanks for the link!